# Why do browsers present selected files as coming from C:\fakepath\ instead of their true local path?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, file-upload

```html
<input type="file"
  onchange="this.nextElementSibling.textContent = this.value;">
<p>
```

When I pick a file from the input above, I get a path like this:

> C:\fakepath\test.csv

or this (Mozilla):

> test.csv

I want the *fully qualified local file path*. How to resolve this issue?

If this is due to browser security issue then what should be the alternate way to do this?

Comment: This is the security implementation of the browser - the browser is protecting you from accessing your disk structure. It might help if you can explain why you want the full path.

Comment: What do you mean by **full url** ? Address of uploaded file ?

Comment: @gor, yes. Say my file in '/home/..../.../mydir/test.csv'

Comment: For the record, IE only gives the "fakepath" bit because they didn't want servers that were "expecting" a path to break.  Otherwise just like other browsers for security reasons you will only get the filename (no path).  More importantly, unless you have malicious intentions I can't see why knowing the path provides anything useful.

Comment: @scunliff, I have upload button on a pop. Using this JS I was trying to fill pass the full url to the "hidden field". I was catching the hidden fields in my handler.

Comment: `browser security issue` ~ if its implemented in the browser (rightly so) then it's highly unlikely you can circumvent it

Comment: @e_maxm What server language are you using (C#, PHP, etc.)? Maybe we can help out with an example of how to handle the uploaded file.

Comment: @e_maxm - what were you going to do with the file/path name in the hidden field? it is still of no use on the server.  That said, JavaScript will not let you copy the filename from the file field for **security reasons** so this won't work anyway.

Comment: I can understanding them not wanting to show the full URL for security reasons but making up c:\fakepath\ seems pretty unprofessional...

Comment: @theycallmemorty: official quote: `This "fakepath" requirement is a sad accident of history`, some more in-depth info and references in [this linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079) (by me), which also covers the OP's question above.

Comment: Gosh darnit, I keep all of my files in `C:\fakepath`, so now everyone knows my directory structure.

Comment: Unless you're using electron or similar, you won't have ways to do that

Answer (score 213):

Some browsers have a security feature that prevents JavaScript from knowing your file's local full path. It makes sense - as a client, you don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem. It would be nice if all browsers did this.

Comment: Then what is the alternate way to know the full url?

Comment: If the browser does not send the local file path, there is no way to find it out.

Comment: Just post the form: the browser will take care of the upload. Your web site doesn't need to know the full path back on the client.

Comment: And what about uploading with ajax (DWR controller)? I want to be able to upload many files before sending the form (like in gmail in fact)

Comment: @ruffp You can only upload with a post so you need to put the upload in a form and submit it. That will still use a standard file upload control to choose the file and you still won't need the full client filename.

Comment: Thanks Rup, finally I found there was a problem with the DWR version 2.0.8 where utils.js was not fully implemented. Using the DWR 3.0.rc2 fixed my problem.

Comment: what's the security problem? Even if javascript knows the absolute file path in local disk, but javascrit can't read & write local file.  And Even if Servers know client file path, what damage can it do to clients? anyone can explain it to me? Thx.

Comment: I doubt there's anything malicious a normal website can do to your local machine without some kind of trusted plugin like Flash or Java. It's more of a privacy thing. For example, if you're uploading from your desktop, you'd be letting the server know your username on your local machine or domain (`c:\users\myname\desktop` or `/Users/myname/Desktop/` or whatever). That's not something a webserver has any business knowing.

Comment: Privacy almost always relates to security and vulnerability as information can be used against someone. Attacks frequently exploit multiple issues to achieve their goals. Anyone not recognizing the dangers should not be allowed near code other than Hello World without additional how-to-be-paranoid workshops.

Comment: @e_maxm, You can put a condition `if(filePath.match(/fakepath/)) {` like $Anand Sharma has provided in his answer. I was also facing same issue and gone with this condition. Doing other settings from `Internet Options` is only know for tech people and not for other people. So better to provide condition and replace `C:\fakepath`. And I also upvoted your question :) for good question.

Comment: Why/how is this actually adding security? JavaScript shouldn't be able to affect the end-users computer's file system, given a file path or not. There are known paths with much higher security risks than anything the client would voluntarily upload, for example the Windows directory is always at C:\Windows, users will be under C:\Users, who cares? How does that information help an attacker in any way (it doesn't)? And why must chrome hide something from the client themselves to do this?

Comment: @Deji As I indicated in a comment, it's more about privacy than it is about specific protection from a single attack. Uploaded file paths often will include the username of the user, which is information that the web server wouldn't have otherwise known. Depending on what's being uploaded and why, this might be enough for a malicious person to do bad things that they wouldn't have been able to with just the file.

Comment: @JoeEnos ... like?

Comment: @Deji A photo manipulation site sees a photo of a person, and along with their username, uses this photo to create a fake social media account to scam either the uploader or one of their friends. I'm sure people who do bad things for a living can give you more examples, but even without a common example, it's simply none of the server's business what my local directory structure or local username is.

Comment: @JoeEnos Many times the full path includes a directory that is .../Users/username/Documents/.... poof now the server (run by some hacker) knows the name of a valid user on your system. One less thing to guess when trying to hack in ... or if someone succeeds in playing man in the middle against you, they found out your user name. (which for 99% of home computers is also the administrator account)

Comment: As an additional example nobody has mentioned, maybe I'm working on a secret project, could even be a competitor to the very site I'm using. I don't want to fear exposing my folder names every time I'm uploading a file. (Not to mention that exposing the user name is a HUGE privacy blunder; what if I'm trying to stay anonymous, but using a real name for my computer account?) Forget hacking, it's about leaking information.

Comment: @Archimedix: I'm interested in taking that "how-to-be-paranoid" workshop. **Which one do you recommend?** Serious question, I've a rather seasoned developer and if there's anything that I've learned, it is that we cannot be paranoid enough.

Comment: @dotancohen in this scenario, one could imagine a porn consumer with a very unique name inferable from the user name saving some video clip to C:\Users\JEdgarHooper\Videos\Porn\AgentsDoingIt.mp4 and uploading it to virustotal.com, which saves the file path and blackmails Hooper. In social media, think about why you post something. What does that post reveal about you? Maybe that you’re working for the CIA, male, like weapons and cat videos, are homophobic (keep saying "That‘s so gay")... a starting point for social engineering. Just challenge yourself to see how things can be used against you.

Comment: @Archimedix: I agree that revealing the path is revealing too much sensitive information, that was never in dispute. I'm asking about your previous comment about some hypothetical workshop which might introduce me to more things to be paranoid about!

Comment: @dotancohen that was the point I tried to make, reading closely, the _world_ and your very behavior is your workshop (though there is a workshop about practical paranoia relating to IT security, along with a few books, not advertising here). Just look as far as your fingertips, but if you have exhausted your personal self already and still do not feel paranoid enough, subscribe to any news, not just IT. The git bomb was just rediscovered, existed on GitHub since at least 2014 in hiding, but similar bombs (ZIP, fork) are much older, which hasn't stopped git devs from making the same mistakes.

Comment: @dotancohen CompuServe was giving you 10 hours of Internet a month for free, any additional usage was charged but you could open the billing information page within CompuServe (which was always free) whilst surfing the open waters to surf forever. Was it a PR stunt? Who knows. WPA2 KRACKed? No, it is a feature to resend data you might have missed, oops, forgot that you should never reuse counters in crypto. This unsuspecting burglar was not too paranoid: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2667413/Burglar-busted-stopping-check-FACEBOOK-victims-computer-forgetting-log-out.html

Answer (score 109):

Use

```
document.getElementById("file-id").files[0].name;
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('file-id').value
```

Comment: In Chrome 44.0.2403.125, this only provides you with the filename.

Comment: Then use document.getElementById("file-id").files[0].path. Works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Loaderon you should post this as an answer!

Comment: @Loaderon didn't work for me. Using chrome 90.0.4430.93

Comment: Do not use `.name` if you want all the file metadata (except for the content)

Comment: `document.getElementById("file-id").files[0].path` does not work any longer @Loaderon?

Comment: @Crashalot I had it as an answer and got some upvotes, then I started to receive downvotes, I guess it no longer works but haven't tried myself.

Comment: `...files[0].path` not working

Answer (score 63):

I use the object FileReader on the input `onchange` event for your input file type! This example uses the readAsDataURL function and for that reason you should have an  tag. The FileReader object also has readAsBinaryString to get the binary data, which can later be used to create the same file on your server

Example:

```
var input = document.getElementById("inputFile");
var fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
fReader.onloadend = function(event){
    var img = document.getElementById("yourImgTag");
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
```

Comment: any idea why even this isn't working on localhost? the source gets set as *src="C:\fakepath\filename.jpg"* but console.logging the image element says the src is a dataURL

Comment: answer: backbone rerendering :/

Comment: You have no idea how much frustration this entry saved.  It's a diamond in the rough ... only 12 up votes but deserving of much more.

Glad I looked further down because the other entries with much higher upvotes weren't working and also FormData() won't do the trick for our purposes.

Well Done!

Comment: The question is asking for the file **path** not the file content.

Comment: @Quentin: yes you are right, but cleary the intent of the OP is to be able to somehow maybe upload the file to the server. Thus this solution would work is certainly very helpful to all people who look for a way of uploading files to a server using JS.

Comment: tried to implement this for a local video ended up crashing my computer :D

Answer (score 36):

If you go to Internet Explorer, Tools, Internet Option, Security, Custom, find the "Include local directory path When uploading files to a server" (it is quite a ways down) and click on "Enable" . This will work

Comment: Is there something similar to Chrome?

Comment: No, this is IE only.

Answer (score 11):

I am happy that browsers care to save us from intrusive scripts and the like. I am not happy with IE putting something into the browser that makes a simple style-fix look like a hack-attack!

I've used a < span > to represent the file-input so that I could apply appropriate styling to the < div > instead of the < input > (once again, because of IE). Now due to this IE want's to show the User a path with a value that's just guaranteed to put them on guard and in the very least apprehensive (if not totally scare them off?!)... MORE IE-CRAP!

Anyhow, thanks to to those who posted the explanation here: [IE Browser Security: Appending "fakepath" to file path in input[type="file"]](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/upload/ie8-upload-control-shows-quot-c-fakepath-quot.aspx), I've put together a minor fixer-upper...

The code below does two things - it fixes a lte IE8 bug where the onChange event doesn't fire until the upload field's onBlur and it updates an element with a cleaned filepath that won't scare the User.

```
// self-calling lambda to for jQuery shorthand "$" namespace
(function($){
    // document onReady wrapper
    $().ready(function(){
        // check for the nefarious IE
        if($.browser.msie) {
            // capture the file input fields
            var fileInput = $('input[type="file"]');
            // add presentational <span> tags "underneath" all file input fields for styling
            fileInput.after(
                $(document.createElement('span')).addClass('file-underlay')
            );
            // bind onClick to get the file-path and update the style <div>
            fileInput.click(function(){
                // need to capture $(this) because setTimeout() is on the
                // Window keyword 'this' changes context in it
                var fileContext = $(this);
                // capture the timer as well as set setTimeout()
                // we use setTimeout() because IE pauses timers when a file dialog opens
                // in this manner we give ourselves a "pseudo-onChange" handler
                var ieBugTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    // set vars
                    var filePath     = fileContext.val(),
                        fileUnderlay = fileContext.siblings('.file-underlay');
                    // check for IE's lovely security speil
                    if(filePath.match(/fakepath/)) {
                        // update the file-path text using case-insensitive regex
                        filePath = filePath.replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
                    }
                    // update the text in the file-underlay <span>
                    fileUnderlay.text(filePath);
                    // clear the timer var
                    clearTimeout(ieBugTimeout);
                }, 10);
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Please note that this doesn't work on IE, hence; I replaced the following : filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('\\')+ 1 , filePath.length)

Answer (score 8):

On Chrome/Chromium based apps like electron you can just use the target.files:

(I'm using React JS on this example)

```
const onChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;

  // this will return C:\fakepath\somefile.ext
  console.log(value);

  const files = event.target.files;

  //this will return an ARRAY of File object
  console.log(files);
}

return (
 <input type="file" onChange={onChange} />
)
```

The `File object` I'm talking above looks like this:

```
{
  fullName: "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\somefile.ext"
  lastModified: 1593086858659
  lastModifiedDate: (the date)
  name: "somefile.ext"
  size: 10235546
  type: ""
  webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

So then you can just get the `fullName` if you wanna get the path.

Note that this would only work on chrome/chromium browsers, so if you don't have to support other browsers (like if you're building an electron project) you can use this.

Comment: If I run your example on https://jscomplete.com/playground in Firefox (use `ReactDOM.render(<input type="file" onChange={onChange} />, mountNode);`), I get an object whose attributes are `lastModified`, `name`, `size`, `type`, and `webkitRelativePath`. Indeed, as others have remarked, being able to get the complete path would in general be a security/privacy issue. So you must have done something else to achieve the result above.

Comment: Yes, it would be a security bug if you could get the unredacted file path.

Comment: @I am L fullName: "C:\Users\myname\Downloads\somefile.ext" is not comming for me when i tried

Answer (score 6):

I came accross the same problem. In IE8 it could be worked-around by creating a hidden input after the file input control. The fill this with the value of it's previous sibling. In IE9 this has been fixed aswell.

My reason in wanting to get to know the full path was to create an javascript image preview before uploading. Now I have to upload the file to create a preview of the selected image.

Comment: If someone wants to see an image before upload, they can view it on their computer.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to send the full path of the uploded file, then you'd probably have to use something like a signed java applet as there isn't any way to get this information if the browser doesn't send it.

Answer (score 2):

Use file readers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#input-file").change(function() {
            var length = this.files.length;
            if (!length) {
                return false;
            }
            useImage(this);
        });
    });

    // Creating the function
    function useImage(img) {
        var file = img.files[0];
        var imagefile = file.type;
        var match = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"];
        if (!((imagefile == match[0]) || (imagefile == match[1]) || (imagefile == match[2]))) {
            alert("Invalid File Extension");
        } else {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(img.files[0]);
        }

        function imageIsLoaded(e) {
            $('div.withBckImage').css({ 'background-image': "url(" + e.target.result + ")" });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you can't find the full path in you localhost by js, but you can hide the fakepath to just show the file name. [Use jQuery to get the file input's selected filename without the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365858/use-jquery-to-get-the-file-inputs-selected-filename-without-the-path/6365883#6365883)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this, I've found, is to use a middleware like Multer. Here's a quick rundown:

1. npm i multer
2. Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your html form.
3. In your backend dock where you're making your post request, require multer (`const multer = require('multer')`)
4. In the same dock, set your upload destination: `const upload = multer({dest:'uploas/'})`. This will automatically create a local folder called 'uploads' where your files will be added. The code I've included shows you how to upload to your local disk storage. If you're using cloud storage (e.g. AWS, Azure, Cloudinary etc.) you can check out the Multer docs to see how to manage that. There aren't too many extra steps though.
5. in your post request, add 'upload.single' (for one file) or 'upload.array' (for multiple files), like this:

```js
router.post('/new', upload.single('image'), async function(req, res) { //'image' should be the name of the input you're sending in the req.body
  console.log(req.file) //note, if you're using 'upload.array', this should be 'req.files'
});
```

the req.file will have a full path name that you can use in your post request. For more information, check out the Multer docs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

You would be able to get at least temporary  created copy of the file path on your machine. The only condition here is your input element should be within a form
What you have to do else is putting in the form an attribute `enctype`, e.g.:

```
<form id="formid" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{url('/add_a_note' )}}">...</form>
```

[image]
you can find the path string  at the bottom.
It opens stream to file and then deletes it.

Comment: The question is asking for "the **local** fully qualified file path". Uploading a copy to the server then getting the path to where it was uploaded to is very different.

Comment: @Quentin Its very simple...Because actually Im not a stackoverflower in full meaning of the word )). First of all writing for myself in future.

Answer (score -3):

Hy  there , in my case i am using asp.net development environment, so i was want to upload those data in asynchronus ajax request , in [webMethod] you can not catch the file uploader since it is not static element , 
so i had to make a turnover for such solution by fixing the path , than convert the wanted image into bytes to save it in DB .

Here is my javascript function , 
hope it helps you:

```
function FixPath(Path)
         {
             var HiddenPath = Path.toString();
             alert(HiddenPath.indexOf("FakePath"));

             if (HiddenPath.indexOf("FakePath") > 1)
             {
                 var UnwantedLength = HiddenPath.indexOf("FakePath") + 7;
                 MainStringLength = HiddenPath.length - UnwantedLength;
                 var thisArray =[];
                 var i = 0;
                 var FinalString= "";
                 while (i < MainStringLength)
                 {
                     thisArray[i] = HiddenPath[UnwantedLength + i + 1];
                     i++;
                 }
                 var j = 0;
                 while (j < MainStringLength-1)
                 {
                     if (thisArray[j] != ",")
                     {
                         FinalString += thisArray[j];
                     }
                     j++;
                 }
                 FinalString = "~" + FinalString;
                 alert(FinalString);
                 return FinalString;
             }
             else
             {
                 return HiddenPath;
             }
         }
```

here only for testing :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             FixPath("hakounaMatata:/7ekmaTa3mahaLaziz/FakePath/EnsaLmadiLiYghiz");
         });
// this will give you : ~/EnsaLmadiLiYghiz
```