# Browse path shows c:\fakepath\filemae.................... how to get exact file path

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to resolve the C:\fakepath ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Hi
   Am using a Jquery to browse a file from hard disk when i select a file, am getting its path as fakepath like below .... any idea how to display the exact file path in text box....?

[image]

Thank you......