# how to remove c fakepath in webkit browser like chrome, safari, opera?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

How to remove c fakepath in webkit browser like chrome, safari, opera ?

in IE And Firefox it's show only file name , it's OK

But in Chrome, opera, safari. It's show C:\fakepath\700.jpg

How can i remove C:\fakepath\ in Chrome, opera, safari.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.inputWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*Using a background color, but you can use a background image to represent a button*/
    background-color: #DDF;
}
.fileInput {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    /*This makes the button huge so that it can be clicked on*/
    font-size:50px;
}
.hidden {
    /*Opacity settings for all browsers*/
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {
    $(".inputWrapper").mousedown(function() {
        var button = $(this);
        button.addClass('clicked');
        setTimeout(function(){
            button.removeClass('clicked');
        },50);
    });

    $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().find('span').text($this.val());
    });
});
});//]]>  
</script>
<div class="inputWrapper" id="inputWrapper" style="height: 56px; width: 128px;">
    <input class="fileInput hidden" type="file" name="file2"/>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to get the file input's selected filename without the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365858/use-jquery-to-get-the-file-inputs-selected-filename-without-the-path)

Comment: Please review answers and mark one.

Answer (score 28):

Just use a regular expression to remove everything before (and including) the last `\`.

```
 var path = "C:\\fakepath\\example.doc";
 var filename = path.replace(/^.*\\/, "");
 console.log(filename);
```

Obviously, you'd get `path` from your file input.

Comment: Warning: this solution is good, but not perfect. If a file name contains a backslash (eg, on Unix systems) you won't get the right file name! A better solution is to use `path.replace(/^C:\\fakepath\\/, "")`

Comment: @stackular yours is not perfect also. and you have typo.
replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");

Comment: @emrah What typo? And not use a regexp to catch `C:\fakepath\` at the beginning of the file name?

Answer (score 22):

And you will get the name of first file.

```
document.getElementById("yourInputElement").files[0].name
```

If you want to get multiple filenames, you have to iterate over `files`.

Comment: Yeah.. moreover, you dont even need jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for this, @Fusion. This is the superlative approach.

Comment: Most importantly this behaviour is covered by HTML standards, whereas the fakepath isn't

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".inputWrapper").mousedown(function() {
        var button = $(this);
        button.addClass('clicked');
        setTimeout(function(){
            button.removeClass('clicked');
        },50);
    });
    $('input[type=file]').on('change', function(e) {
        var filename = $(e.currentTarget).val().replace(/^.*\\/, "");
        $this.parent().find('span').text(filename);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

Use Below Code :

```
<label for="file" class="input input-file"><div class="button"><input type="file" onchange="this.parentNode.nextSibling.value = this.value" name="uploadfiliron" class="uploadimg" data-gotfile='uploadimg-1'>Browse</div><input type="text" readonly class="uploadimg-1"></label>
```

And This is script

```
<script>$('body').on('change','.uploadimg',function(e){
var filename = $(this).val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');
var getft = $(this).attr('data-gotfile');
console.log(getft+" "+filename);
if(filename=='')
    {
        $('.'+getft).val('No file chosen');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.'+getft).val('Your file name: '+filename);
    }});</script>
```

Comment: Unix filenames can contain backslashes, this solution doesn't account for that.