# How to get upload file name using upload field "name" attribute in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I get upload file name after click the submit button. Below in the file upload field.

```
<input class="required-field" type="file" value="" name="cover_image">
```

I've tried with below but it not get the value.

```
var filename = $("[name='cover_image']", form).val();
```

Here I don't have ID fro the input filed but is it possible to get upload file name?

Comment: what is `form`? a var or the actual `form` tag.

Comment: I use `form` for get the value in filed. ex: for get text field value I've used `var magcode = jQuery("[name='magcode']", form).val();`

Comment: This question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365858/use-jquery-to-get-the-file-inputs-selected-filename-without-the-path

Comment: @miuranga your `form` is a variable, we don't know what its value is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the full path using `.val()` for getting filename you can use:

```
 $('[name="cover_image"].required-field').val().split('\\').pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var filename = $("[name='cover_image']", 'form').val();
```

or one suggestion is to use form's id here:

```
var filename = $("[name='cover_image']", "formID").val();
```

or you can try this too:

```
var form = $('YourForm');
var filename = form.find("[name='cover_image']").val();
```

you can use `form` because this is the jQuery object and you can find the specific element in it.

Comment: You don't need to wrap `form` in `$()` as it's already a jQuery object.