# Populate text field from file select

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to fill the text box with the file name that is selected in file upload?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textbox = document.getElementById('fiil');
var fileselect = document.getElementById('uploadData');

fileselect.onchange = function(){
      textbox.value = textbox.value  + this.value; //to appened
     //textbox.innerHTML = this.value; 
}
```

here is my html code:

```
<form  id="upload" name="upload" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/upload_gen048" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return verify_upload()" >
<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<b style=" padding:.3em; font-size:15px;color:white"> </b><input style="border:1px solid" type="text" onfocus="true"  name="fiil" id="fiil" value=""size="30" />
<input type="file" name="uploadData" id="uploadData" style=""/>
```

Comment: no sir it isn't nothing appears on my textbox

Comment: Seems to be working for me https://jsfiddle.net/6d0hqv36/

Comment: Just a heads up: you'll notice odd behaviour (ie: "fake" being in the textbox) when using this method in IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to get the file input's selected filename without the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365858/use-jquery-to-get-the-file-inputs-selected-filename-without-the-path)

Comment: That's weird @PhiterFernandes you are right its working, but I dont know why it is not working on my page, I double check the name and IDs if there is a duplicate but there is none.

anyways I already found the answer somewhere. thanks to Phiter for that site that you gave I can use it in the future.

Can I add an answer to my post? because I have the working code now.

Comment: You absolutely can, make it clear and perhaps your answer will be of usage for other users in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys~! I learned a lot from this site and it has a good community, back to my project now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textbox = document.getElementById('fiil');
var fileselect = document.getElementById('uploadData');

function fileSelect()
{
    var x =  document.getElementById('uploadData').value;
    var fileName = x.match(/[^\/\\]+$/);

    document.getElementById('fiil').value = fileName;
}
```

I just added `onChange="fileSelect()` in the input file here:

```
<form  id="upload" name="upload" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/upload_gen048" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return verify_upload()" >

<div class="col-lg-4"></div>
<b style=" padding:.3em; font-size:15px;color:white"> </b>
<input style="border:1px solid" type="text" onfocus="true"  name="fiil" id="fiil" value=""size="30" />

<input type="file" name="uploadData" id="uploadData" onChange="fileSelect();" style=""/>
```

Comment: If it solves your question, mark it as the answer, please.

Comment: it says that you can accept your own answer in 2 days, that is why I still can mark a check :( sorry

Comment: I see. So just don't forget to do it, please. It'll help others.

Comment: BTW I have removed commented code out of your answer. Code in the questions and answers should be short, clear and contain only related things.