# Allow user to upload images on x folder chrome extension without submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to allow the user to upload images on chrome extension example folder name (upload) and without submit button

```
<form action="/upload">
  <input type="file" name="myimages" accept="image/*">
</form>
```

show images

```
<span class="AvGbtn" id="AvBgIds" style="background-image: url(Here i want to show upload images url
); background-size: 100% 100%;" oncontextmenu="return false">  
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( '#myimages' ).change(function() {
      var filename = $('input[type=file]').val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
      $( '#myform' ).submit();
      $( '#uploaded').append('<img src="/upload/' + filename + '"/>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="/upload">
  <input type="file" name="myimages" id="myimages" accept="image/*">
</form>
<div id="uploaded">
</div>
```

Use the onchange event of the file upload field to submit the form.

EDIT:

Added functionality to display the uploaded image in the div below the form.

Credits: [Use jQuery to get the file input's selected filename without the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365858/use-jquery-to-get-the-file-inputs-selected-filename-without-the-path)

Comment: Thanks for your help, is ok and with submit button, just i want to show the upload images on this div `<span class="AvGbtn" id="AvBgIds" style="background-image: url(Here i want to show upload images url
); background-size: 100% 100%;" oncontextmenu="return false">  
</span>`

Comment: so i want to allow user to upload multi images and show all images in that div? i don't know if that is possible or no?

Comment: Thanks you, I have not tested that! (health reasons) but I accept it as a correct answer. Thanks again.