# How get a real path value to file that store local on HDD from input or FileUpload?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have two file uploaders:

```
<input name="targetFile" runat="server" id="File1" type="file" /> 
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

When I click to choose file (for example D:\Test.txt) the way to file appears on control, but when I get value control in javascript:

```
obj = document.getElementById("File1");
```

value of the path to file store local:

```
obj.value = "C:\fakepath\Test.txt"
```

I need to get actualy "D:\Test.txt" string on javascript. Can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve the C:\fakepath ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Long answer: see link above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a

```
subst D: C:\fakepath\
```

?
or how do you mix c: and d:?

Comment: I don't now. I choose any file on C: or D: and string always C:\fakepath\ and + file name at the end of string.