# How to get file path form input tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am using input tag with attribute `type="file"` in HTML.
If I browse and select image and try to get path of file with `$('file_upload').val()` in script it returns path as `"C:\fakepath\img_name"`*

I need to get this path and set as default to input tag from JavaScript.

Please help me with this.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {$('#imgUpload_edit').change(
        function(){if ($(this).val()) {alert($('#imgUpload_edit').val());} }); });
```

HTML:

```
<FORM id="frmImgUpload_edit" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="" METHOD="POST">
    <label for="imgUpload_edit" id="bold-text_edit">Select an image for the Device Type:</label>
    <input type="file" id="imgUpload_edit" name="deviceTypeImage_edit" size="10000"/>
    <div id="imageEditDeviceType"></div>
</FORM>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, that can't be done. It's a security feature.

Answer (score -1):

Can you create an input element using jQuery instead setting the value attribute of the input to the val of the element you want to get it from?

```
jQuery('input').attr("value",$('#imgUpload_edit').val())
```

You can string additional .attr such as id, etc as needed.

Comment: That would still get the security filtered file path.

Comment: What if the path is "http://...." as opposed to a local workspace like "C:..."?  Then it wouldn't be a security issue.

Comment: — I've never seen a file input that accepted an HTTP URI. The control is designed to upload files from the user's file system to the website.

Comment: sorry, misread original question... would be a security breach to do this.