# How to get exact file location in input file type using Javascript/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, path, filepath

How do I get the full path file from `<input type="file />`?

I kept getting `C:\fakepath\[filename]`

Here 's my script

```
$(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
alert($('input#path').val());
});
});

<input type="file" id="path" />
<button>Read</button>
```

What I want to do is to pass the file path from Javascript to PHP then read/rewrite it.

---

UPDATE: I tried the following but I still get the fakepath. Im using Chrome.

```
$(function(){
$('button').click(function(){
$.post(
'test2.php', {
path: $('input#path').val()
}, function(data){
alert(data);
}
);
});
});
```

test2.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST['path'];
?>
```

Comment: It't not allowed to read the filepath from the input field. You get a temporary path to not compromise the users file system. I think you might use HTML5 File API for newer browsers to be able to read the file, otherwise, you have to process it on the server.

Comment: I tried sending it into PHP using $.post(), I still get the fake path

Answer (score 1):

You just need to post the data with javascript using ajax. The "fakepath" is a security feature by the browser.

[How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)