# compatibility issue with <input type="file"> in google chrome browser

Tags: html

my requirement is to select a file through

```
<input type="file">
```

and send the location of the selected file to a

```
<form>
```

so i wrote the html code as follows:

```
 <form method="post" action="Xmlsubmit">
 <input name="path" type="file" id="t" />
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="submit">
 </form>
```

This worked with out any problem in IE, but when i try this with google chrome and mozilla firefox i am facing "File not found exception".
Is there any worke arround to make this work with google chrome and mozilla firefox?

What i need is:
I just wanted to send the location of the selected file to form element

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: File inputs are designed to allow users to send *files*, not information about the structure of their file system.

Comment: @Quentin That's the same problem iam facing, but i thought this is a simple problem and can be solved, but this is entirely out of my knowledge, Thanks for the response mean while i will try figuring out a solution for this problem.. Thanks for the Response :)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to set the forms enctype..

try 
`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is not solved.. even after adding this line to form element neither google chrome nor mozilla firefox worked :(