# How to avoid displaying "C:fakepath" in browsers

Tags: javascript, html

How to avoid displaying "C:fakepath" while file uploading. While uploading the file javacript method is called to set the selected path im my case

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Comment: Search this site for your issue if not then only create new questions... by refer your history couple of questions you asked are marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser security feature that is implemented.

According to the specifications of `HTML5`, a file upload control should not reveal the real local path to the file you have selected, if you manipulate its value string with JavaScript. Instead, the string that is returned by the script, which handles the file information is `c:\fakepath`.

If you still want to get rid of this fakepath you may check out this site

[How To Get Rid of C:\FakePath in IE When Uploading A File to the Website](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-get-rid-of-cfakepath-in-ie-when-uploading-a-file-to-the-website-fix/)

Hope it helps.