# Getting the file location from a web application

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a new project, and its **NOT** going to be placed on a server but I want to when the user uses a fileupload, it will get the link, of that file the user uploads... I know javascript can't do this..

Is there any other way of doing this?

Getting a file location from a file input box...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: since protecting the file path is part of browser security, the only possible way would be flash, a java applet or something similar

Comment: Yer, was thinking about that ok thanks...