# Input file validation using Jasny v3.1.3 and jQuery Validator v1.13.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jasny-bootstrap

I've been trying to valid an input file field that uses Jasny v3.1.3 but the validation is only done when the form submit button is clicked, that I explicitly call `$('#exercicio-form').valid()` method from jQuery Validator v1.13.1.

Please take a look at the fiddle I'm working on: http://jsfiddle.net/Luf0ks9b/3/

Note that when I insert some invalid name in the first field and click in somewhere else in the page, the validation is done and the error message is prompted. However, when I upload an invalid file format in the file input field, the validation is NOT done promptly. It is done, though, when I click in submit button.

I already took a look at this question: [jQuery Validate Plugin, Bootstrap, Jasny Bootstrap File Input RegEx - Validation Working in Firefox Not in Chrome/IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387874/jquery-validate-plugin-bootstrap-jasny-bootstrap-file-input-regex-validation)
In the fiddle example of it, something similar to what I want to have is done. When some wrong format file is uploaded, the error is prompt displayed. But, in this answer, they used Jasny v2.3.0. A different version from what I'm using.

Any suggestion or comments are always welcome!

EDIT

Adding HTML and jQuery code:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-2 column"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 column">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Some title..</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="exercicio-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Enter with some name..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
                                <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i>
 <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>

                                </div> <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file">
                        <span class="fileinput-new">Search..</span>
 <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>

                                <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
                                </span> <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <button value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitExercicio" data-loading-text="Submitting.." style="float:right">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 column"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#exercicio-form').validate({
    rules: {
        nome: {
            minlength: 5,
            required: true
        },
        file: {
            required: true,
            //accept: "image/jpeg, image/pjpeg"
            accept: "video/mp4"
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        console.log("highlight");
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        console.log("success");
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        console.log("errorPlacement");

        // if element is file type, we put the error message in its grand parent
        if (element.prop("type") === "file") {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});

$("#submitExercicio").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('#exercicio-form').valid()) {
        $('#submitExercicio').button('loading');
    } else {
        alert("Invalid fields still!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Bootstrap, Jasney, or the `click` handler. Remove these things and the result is the same.  It seems like a bug with the plugin.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/n73es6qc/

Comment: @Sparky, in your fiddle after removing bootstrap and jasney the result is the expected one, right? So you are saying the bug may be related with bootstrap or jasny libraries?

Comment: Anyway, have you seen this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/4fu5S/5/

they used jasny, bootstrap and jquery validator and the error is displayed without the necessity to click on submit button

Comment: No, I removed the stated items and the problem remains for me.  In other words, I see no difference, which is why I think maybe it's a bug with jQuery Validate.

Comment: This is weird.. for me, your fiddle worked as expected. After I upload some image, for example, and click on some place in the page, the error msg is displayed. I saw this behavior both in Chrome and Firefox