# Resolve C:\fakepath for file input using pure javascript or angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to get the full path of the selected file using pure javascript or angular 2?
I need the user to pick the excel file which I then need to send to c# WEB API controller method for further processing.

For now I got this:

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile"  class="button-pop-up-footer1">
```

js

```
var selectedFilePath = document.getElementById("selectedFile").value;
```

But when i select the file located at: C:\users\owner\desktop\myfile.xls, I get the path as C:\fakepath\myfile.xls.

Anyone got ideas on how to resolve this and get the full path to the file without compromising the security?

Comment: No. It is not possible

Comment: @AbhishekAnand don't write your answer in the comments. Describe why it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254118/fakepath-issue-in-chrome-browser

Comment: @Doggo I don't know the full answer, So i cant do that

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to get the full path of the selected file using pure javascript or angular 2?

No. It would be a serious security problem.

> I need the user to pick the excel file which I then need to send to c# WEB API controller method for further processing.

That's fine, you don't need the real path for that. Just use an `input type="file"` and post the form to your controller (or use an up-to-date [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) or [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to do it with ajax — Angular's `http` service should be up to the task on a modern browser).

Comment: Could you share some ajax or better angular 2 code that would post the file to the WEB API? Or a link to some tutorial where I can see the implementation. Thanks for the answer btw :D

Comment: @ŽeljkoKrnjić: No, don't really do Angular, but I can't imagine such a thing would be difficult to find.