# How to give path of local folder to webkit directory

Tags: php

I am using webkit directory to upload folders into the server. Its working fine. I wanted to know if it possible to give path of folder to webkit directory to be uploaded to server without using dialog? Like I know which folder to be uploaded on server, I will give its path to webkit directory and it will upload full folder for me?

For example, after the user selects `foo.html`, can the folder foo be uploaded automatically?

```
 /foo.html
 /foo/...
```

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

That is not allowed for **security reasons**. You cannot grab arbitrary files from the file system without user interaction. Otherwise, what would stop websites from stealing anything they wanted from a user's computer?

The user must select a file/folder for it to be uploaded.

If you want that kind of functionality, you would need a native app.

Once the user has selected a file, you cannot access the path of the file either. All modern browsers provide false paths when you ask for the value of the file picker input. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath) about *unsuccessfully attempting* to get that information.

Comment: sir actually what i wanted is user selects the file and there will be a folder with the same filename both the file and folder will be uploaded to server. i have done folder uploading to the server the only thing which is driving me crazy is how to give folder path when user selects the file.

Comment: Ah, so after the user selects a file, you want the name of the folder? I don't think this is possible, again for security reasons. I think it's safari, that will claim the file is `C:/fakepath/filename.txt`

Comment: You might be able to instruct the user to select both, the file and the folder, if webkit directory accepts multiple inputs.

Comment: sir can u answer my question. Suppose that i have a file in my local system i want this file to be uploaded to server. I will choose its path from a dialog. But i want to give its path by myself without opening a dialog?\

Comment: You cannot programatically set the path of a file/folder to be uploaded. It must be through a dialog with user interaction for security reasons.

Comment: supposedly, I have a dilaog i have chosen a file now its path is save some where i wanted to know where that path is save?

Comment: You cannot relyably access the file's path on the user's computer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Answer (score -1):

You cannot upload a folder as a whole , but you could upload multiple  files at the same time.

This is a code excerpt from w3schools.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Select images: <input type="file" name="img" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Adding the keyword **multiple** to the file input tag enables you to select multiple files to upload.

Comment: i have uploaded folder as a whole