# Trying to load a text file into a <p> tag, why is it not working?

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I've been looking at other stackoverflow questions pertaining to this and I do not understand why this snippet of code is not working. Right now I am first just trying to get the text to console log to see if it will work at all. I am following line-by-line other people's code it will just not work for this case, and I am unsure why.

```
const file = "1.txt";

let reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.result;
    const lines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    console.log(lines.join('\n'));
};

reader.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: It looks like `.readAsText()` method requires a `Blob` or `File` object, but you are passing a string. I suspect that's why there's an issue. I suggest adding a `reader.onerror` handler and observing any errors that occur.

Comment: Where and how are you running this code? Is the parent page in a `file://` context or a `http://` context?

Comment: where is `1.txt` physically located?

Comment: You can't do this. `readAsTextFile` expects a Blob or a File object, not an URL. You've to get a file using <input type="file">, and pass a file user has chosen, or read the file from your server using AJAX.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, this is making a lot more sense. To answer Dai's question, the target file is located in the root folder. So now I am wondering if there is a method for targeting the file without using AJAX or having a user select the file, it appears that there isn't according to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115057/javascript-read-file-without-using-input)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this specific issue I found that the fetch() function was the key to my issue. If you do something like:

```
fetch('1.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
      // Do something with your data
      console.log(data);
  });
```

Thank you to all the comments I received it helped me find this solution!