# How does Facebook get the full path of my local file?

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, path, drag-and-drop

If you click on the <kbd>Post</kbd> on the top right, then drop an image onto the box, Facebook will fail to recognize it as an image and tries to read it as a link. This is not the main point though.

The weird part is that it knows what the fullpath is.

[image]

This shouldn't be happening since Chrome is sandboxed, and every path, in theory, [should be changed to "fakepath" for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851614/283863).

Somehow Facebook managed to do that. But the question is, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows XP sends the whole path with the content type `text/uri-list`.

Here's a snippet that reproduces this fact:

```
<textarea ondrop="console.log(event.dataTransfer.getData('text/uri-list')); event.preventDefault();">
</textarea>
```

Comment: It returns `about:blank` on Windows 8... Weird.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I cannot test Windows 8. Have a look at `event.dataTransfer.types`

Comment: It returns an Array,`["text/uri-list", "Files"]`

Comment: Okay it works now when I do `e = event.dataTransfer; console.log(e.getData(e.types[0]));` I believe this is a bug or if it isn't then this really is a security hole.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I think it's as security hole and should be reported