# Changing upload placeholder after chose file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code currently:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row upload">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="col-md-12">
 <label for="file" class="filebutton">No file has been selected</label>
 <input style="opacity:0" type="file" name="file" id="file" />
 </form> 
 </div><!--End of row upload-->
```

**CSS:**

```
label {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    width: 500px;
    height:50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #777777;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
```

As you can see, when file is chosen, the placeholder still remains the same. I want placeholder to be file directory when file is chosen.

**FIDDLE:**  http://jsfiddle.net/7rtJ5/

Comment: "I want placeholder to be _file directory_ when file is chosen." - that is [not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath) in many browsers for security reasons. The file name only is available.

Answer (score 1):

test this :

HTML :

```
<div class="row upload">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post" class="col-md-12">
        <input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
        <label for="file" class="filebutton">No file has been selected</label>
        <input style="opacity:0" type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    </form> 
  </div><!--End of row upload-->
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("file").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1- html
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
        <span>Upload</span>
        <input type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```

2- css

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

to change value you need this javascript code :

3-

```
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
```

Comment: this code from http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/

Comment: This doesn't work at all. Can you apply it to my code on jsfiddle please?