# How to get uploaded image full path using Java or JavaScript?

Tags: java, file-upload, filepath

Here i have demo.jsp page where i have form in that im uploading image file and submitting,after submit it goes to servlethomepage,where i need to get the uploaded image path,how can i get it?Anybody guide me please?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ImageResizing</title>
    <script>
        function  validate() {                           
            if (fileName.length == "") {                  
                alert("Please Select Image");
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("uploadImgForm").submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        out.println("<form method='post' action='Result' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='uploadImgForm' name='uploadImgForm'>");
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr><td><input type='file' multiple='multiple' accept='image/*' id='Imgfile' name='Imgfile'></td></tr>");    
        out.println("<tr><td></td></tr>");
        out.println("<tr><td><input type='button' value='Show Images' onclick='validate()'></td></tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</form>");
    %>
</body>
```

How to get choosen image path in Result Servlet,i.e.,C:\users\Pictures\logo.jpg,help me anybody?

Comment: The browser doesn't send the real file path. You can't get it.

Comment: There are security reasons to do this. Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Comment: @dystroy,is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Ask your user to enter the path in a text field. You won't be able to use a chose file dialog.

Comment: suppose when i choose a image present in c:/users/logos/sunny.png,for this i'm getting sunny.png but i need i.e.,(c:/ to /sunny.png) from where i select that path i need.Could you give me any solution if possible.