# Jquery fileupload not giving me correct path

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have file upload html code as:

```
<input type="text" id="txtSelectedFile" value="Select a file" class="sloInputBox" />
                        <input type="file"  id="fUploadArtifact" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 45px;border-radius: 4px;" />
```

And Jquery to get its path as:

```
$(function()
    {
        $('#fUploadArtifact').on('change',function ()
        {

            $('#txtSelectedFile').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

But each time although i take any file from any of the drive it gives me wrong path as:

```
C:\fakepath\Readme.txt
```

I have selected file from `E:\Observations\Readme.txt`

But it given me `C:\fakepath\Readme.txt`

What can be the mistake?

Please help me.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to security reasons it is not possible to get actual file path when using html  file type.

Comment: But what if i want to use path for further reasons?

Comment: @Messi , Using Client side script,You just cant,as browser doesnot allow period..

Comment: @Messi go server side

Answer (score 1):

Its a security feature to prevent JavaScript from knowing your file's local path

Answer (score 1):

Almost all browsers have a security feature that prevents javascript from knowing your file's local full path. It makes sense - as a client, you don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem. It would be nice if all browsers did this.

You may get good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)