# How to copy file path in to span in addition to the input control itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-io

So far I tried this:
JS:

```
function Copy(copyfrom, copyto) {
    document.getElementById(copyto).value = copyfrom.value;
}
```

And HTML code look like this:

```
    <div>
        <input type="file" onchange="Copy(this, 'txtFileName');" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <span id="txtFileName" type="text" readonly="readonly" />

    </div>
```

I want To copy the selected file name/path to different span,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="file"..>` will not show textbox in chrome and safri browser, you can configure the display styles by CSS itself, go to the link [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Answer (score 2):

From [Joe Enos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851614/1817690) you don't need to get server path

> Some browsers have a security feature that prevents javascript from
>   knowing your file's local full path. It makes sense - as a client, you
>   don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem. It
>   would be nice if all browsers did this.

And to get the name of file, try to use `innerText property` of span instead of `value` as value works on form element fields try this,

```
function Copy(copyfrom, copyto) {
    document.getElementById(copyto).innerText = copyfrom.value;
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/jikowezu/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to security reasons.

For more details, see: [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)