# file browser with specific path

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a file uploader. but I want to upload from a folder on the server so the path of the browser is restricted to

C:\wamp\www\JSSoundRecorder\upload

how can I specify the path in the html input file??
html code:

```
<button id="id">Open</button>
<input id="yourinputname" type="file" name="yourinputname" style="display: none;" />
```

jquery code:

```
$('#id').on('click', function() {
$('#yourinputname').trigger('click');
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/QVAC7/

Comment: Umm... are you sure you want _client_ to restrict to the specified path? To me, that path seems where you would _store_ already uploaded files.

Comment: can you explain more please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible due to security reasons, some browsers do  not allow you to even know the local file's path, let alone set it.

> Some browsers have a security feature that prevents javascript from
>   knowing your file's local full path. It makes sense - as a client, you
>   don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem. It
>   would be nice if all browsers did this.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851614/1817690

Comment: how will I restrict the open file to the file on the serever?

Comment: You can't.  Its not possible due to security reasons.