# Javascript: how I can read files and folders from usb flash drive

Tags: javascript, pdf, filesystems

I want print PDF files from usb flash.
Now I decide do this with Mozilla Firefox and Plugin R-kiosk trought open libruary PDF.js
But still have a problem: how read folders and files to build tree without <_input /> cause it allow user get in system.
Any idea? Thx
May be you can give advice the best way to realise idea without browser... But I don't work with pdf libruaries, output and rendering of pages I have simply understanding, but I can't say this about silent printing of document

Comment: What are you asking? First make an attempt at coding it yourself and post back when you run into trouble. Also trying to do this browser based is horrible.

Comment: Not possible in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.  Browsers like Firefox generally won't let you have access to the local file system / disk structure for security reasons.  Even if you knew the local path of the PDF, [it wouldn't be of much help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4851614/3474146).