# Opening file dialog and identifying file exact location

Tags: angularjs

Currently, I enter the exact file location like "c:\mydir\myfile.txt" in the input text box and hit the submit button. This gets captured as a string and posted to my webapi controller.

```
    <div data-ng-controller="fileCtrl">
        <form novalidate class="simple-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter full file path here.." data-ng-model="filePath" />
            <input type="submit" data-ng-click="LoadFilePath()" value="Submit" />

            <div ui-grid="{ data: Rates }" class="grid"></div>

            <p>Copy / Paste : </p>
            <textarea style="height:200px; width:1000px; overflow:scroll;">{{InsertSQL}}</textarea>

        </form>
    </div>

app.controller('fileCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.LoadFilePath = function () {
        //console.log('file path is ' + $scope.filePath);
        $http
            .post('http://localhost:1229/api/Rates' + '/processfile', '"' + $scope.filePath + '"')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.Rates = data.Rates;
                $scope.InsertSQL = data.InsertSQL;
            });
    }
}]);
```

I want to

1) click the button

2) choose file name from the windows explorer

3) choose the above mentioned file.

4) take the PATH of the file and submit to the web api controller

How can I do that in angularjs?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you google around I'm fairly certain you'll find some useful info. As a hint try changing the first <input> from "type=text" to "type=file" then go from there.

Comment: I did google and looked at the search results but did not find any thing that would work. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: As another hint, once you have selected the file, the <input> value will be the path to the file. Simple string manipulation should get you what you want. Then the rest is easy.... ;o)

Comment: If you post as an answer.. I will check it and mark as an answers.

Comment: sorry.. spoke too soon. that did not work.. I had it marked hard coded in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first `<input>` from "type=text" to "type=file" then once you have selected the file, the `<input>` value will be the path to the file.

Simple string manipulation should get you what you want. Then the rest is easy.... ;o)

**EDIT**

It is not possible to get the PATH, just the filename: [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: sorry this did not work. I will keep trying.. filename in the web api controller is coming as undefined.

Comment: Bad news..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath