# jQuery File Upload - Get Folder Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using [JQuery FileUpload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) in my web application. Things are working fine. Now i want to extend the behavior and get the folder name from uploaded file. Requirement is to get the folder name when user drop a file on page or select it through the file selection dialog. For this i tried to use [callback](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) "`fileuploadchange`" and "`fileuploaddrop`". Both worked and i was able to get the selected file collection i.e `data.files` but `data.files[0]` didn't contains any information about the source folder. Any idea on how this can be achieved ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to get the path as browsers hide that information. It's a security feature. To learn more see this post: [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Answer (score 2):

You can only get info on what the user decides to "give" you, for security reasons. You might get that functionality by using some flash plugin, but with html/js you are not allowed into the users pc, not even folder names (thankfully)