# Path of file, show "fakepath" instead a full path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload

I have one issue to resolve my problem. My problem is to get the full path of local image. 
I get my path as: "/fipcurren/mytestfolder/imgs/school.jpeg" and my program showed "C:\fakepath\school.jpg".

My code to get path are:

In HTML file:

```
<input id="imagePath" class="file"  type="file" multiple data-min-file-count="1" accept="image/*">
```

In JavaScript file:

```
data.imagePath = document.getElementById("imagePath").value;
```

I try this above, but not resolve the problem:

```
data.imagePath = document.getElementById("imagePath").files[0].name;
```

Someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: it's a security issue.
look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath