# Why using Chrome and IE when I use the val() function to retrieve the name of the selected file into an input tag it start with "C:\fakepath\"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

Using **Chrome** and **Internet Explorer** I am finding the following problem related how to obtain the file name inserted into an input tag using **jQuery**.

So I have the following situation: into a page I have this **input** tag:

```
<input id="rendicontoAllegato" class="form-control" style="height: 30px; padding: 0px;" type="file">
```

And a div having **id="nomeDocumentoRendicontazione"** that will contain the name of the file selected into the previous **input** tag:

```
<div id="nomeDocumentoRendicontazione"></div>
```

And associated to the **change** event of this input file I have this jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // When the user select a new fine into the input tag:
    $("#rendicontoAllegato").change(function() {

        // Retrieve the name of the selected file and put it into the hidden div having id="nomeDocumentoRendicontazione":
        var selectedFileName = $("#rendicontoAllegato").val();          
        $('#nomeDocumentoRendicontazione').text(selectedFileName);
    });
 });
```

As you can see the previous script when the user select a new fine into the input tag change the value into the div having **id="nomeDocumentoRendicontazione"**.

Using FireFox it works fine and if I select a file name **cat.jpg** in the div I have the value **cat.jpg**.

But if I use Chrome or Internet Explorer, after the file selection in the div I have the following value **C:\fakepath\cat.jpg**

Why? How can I obtain only the file name and not the **C:\fakepath** before it using Chrome and Internet Explorer

Comment: Chop off `C:\fakepath\\` with a regex maybe? - *edit* wow getting `\` into a comment as a code string is tricky :)

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the prefix if it's there:

```
    var selectedFileName = $("#rendicontoAllegato").val()
        .replace(/^C:.*\\/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of security reasons... Following question has some fine answers:

[How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)