# Select a file through input type="file" and append the source file to video element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select a file and after clicking a button, want to load the file into a video element, which should play immediately.
Trying to input the file through `type="text"` works, but that would require me to type the link of the file. What I want is being able to select the file, like through explorer.
`type="file"` allows me to select the file through explorer, but after that I cannot append the file into `video.src` because `value` property returns `fakepath` instead of the real path. Is there another way to do it?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using File For Streaming</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="file" id="videoUrl"/>
<button onClick="play()">Play Video</button>
<video id="videoPlayer" height="400" width="400" autoplay controls muted></video>
    <script>
        function play() {
            var videoUrl = document.getElementById('videoUrl').value;
            alert(videoUrl);
            var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
            videoPlayer.src = videoUrl;
            videoPlayer.load();
            videoPlayer.play();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Comment: @prasad I had already viewed that before asking my question. It didn't resolve my issue. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method, with your uploaded `input.files[0]` to feed your `<source>`'s `src`, then call the `.load()` method of your `<video>`.

```js
inp.onchange = function(){
  source.src = URL.createObjectURL(inp.files[0]);
  vid.load();
  // even if it's just a pointer to the real file here
  vid.onended = function(){
      URL.revokeObjectURL(vid.currentSrc);
    };
  }
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls>
  <source id="source"/>
</video>
<input id="inp" type="file" accept="video/*">
```