# upload image in folder MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am beginner in asp.net and trying to upload the image in my project Images folder but it is not uploading it in desired folder. Anybody please give me suggestion.

**Create.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Lenses", FormMethod.Post,
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>lens</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lens_img, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "lens_img")] lens lens, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/")
                                                          + file.FileName);
            lens.lens_img = file.FileName;
        }
        db.lenses.Add(lens);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(lens);
}
```

Comment: I can't see any `Submit` button in your `Razor code`.

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file is reaching the controller action and `file` parameter is not null, then you should be using `Path.Combine` method to generate the correct path, do not use string concatenation for this, you should try it in following way:

```
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/"), file.FileName);
```

For more clarity, let's break in to two steps:

```
var mappedPath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/");
file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(mappedPath, file.FileName);
```

Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125127/asp-net-mvc-4-c-sharp-httppostedfilebase-how-do-i-store-file/25125284#25125284) as well which is related.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Be aware that `Path.Combine` will fail if `file.FileName` is a path itself, e.g. `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\myFile.jpg`. So I'd wrap a `Path.GetFileName()` around `file.FileName`.

Comment: in posted `file` object in above case it will only contain the filename with extension

Comment: I thought so, too. But one day we ran an application in the Intranet as you do quite often and accessed it with IE. Now Internet Explorer has a special zone for that, in which it passes on the whole file path instead of the name. I just tested the code and the result was the whole file path, see here: http://imgur.com/a/5gmPO
We had this question here a few days ago with the `IFormFile` class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718080/asp-net-core-file-upload-issue/44719038#44719038

Comment: put a break point and see if `file.SaveAs` executes without any exception

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Sure it saves without an exception, but it saves in the wrong directory/overwrites the uploaded file with the same content.