# React simple form file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, formsy-react

I am writing out a form as a React component. I am able to successfully post/patch form data to my server (Rails 5 API). However, I am struggling to see how I attach a file to the payload.

With my current file upload implementation, when the form is posted to the server the params look like this:

```
  Parameters: {"theme"=>{"slug"=>"sonair", ... "primary_asset_attachment"=>{"0"=>{}}}, "theme_id"=>"sonair"}
```

My expectation was the `primary_asset_attachment` would contain a reference to the file.

```
    <FRC.Form
      onSubmit         =   { this.submitForm }
      validationErrors =   { this.state.validationErrors } >

      .... contents elided ....

      <File
        name           =   "primary_asset_attachment"
        label          =   "Theme Image"
        help           =   "Please attach an image"
      />
    </FRC.Form>
```

I am using a React plugin called [Formsy](https://github.com/twisty/formsy-react-components), if this helps.

There are obviously some fairly critical steps I am missing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164372/prevent-redirect-on-file-upload-through-form-submittal-react-express-multer/47183642#47183642 for how I handle uploading files in React

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `<File />` component is very similar to the other `<Input />` components, but instead of returning the `input` element's `value` (which contains a [fake path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath) for security reasons), it returns a [HTML5 FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) as the component's value.

To upload this data, use [`FormData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileUpDown) and then upload using `XMLHttpRequest` or [`fetch`](https://github.com/github/fetch#file-upload).

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way to tackle this is to use an input of type file, eg.

```
<input type="file" onChange={yourChangeHandler}/>
```

and the corresponding event handler function as follows:

```
function yourChangeHandler(event){
  let yourfile = event.target.files; 
}
```

I've managed to store this in a FormData object and sent it using axios with no problems at all