# File upload with multer refreshes React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

**Update**

This is happening because of hot-reloading comes with Creact React App.
Related issues:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/566

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4095

---

I am trying to learn file upload with Nodejs, Express, Multer and React for frontend. I achieved to upload files. There is a problem I struggle, not always but most of the time the whole app refreshes after upload. Here is the relevant code.

**My simple form**

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    id="file"
                    onChange={this.handleFileChange}
                />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

**handleFileChange and handleFormSubmit**

```
handleFormSubmit = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( "file", this.state.file );
    axios.post( "/api/upload", formData );
}

handleFileChange = ( e ) => {
    this.setState( { file: e.target.files[ 0 ] } );
}
```

**Related express route code**

```
const express = require( "express" );
const multer = require( "multer" );
const storage = multer.diskStorage( {
    destination( req, file, cb ) {
        cb( null, "client/public/images" );
    },
    filename( req, file, cb ) {
        cb( null, `${ Date.now() }-${ file.originalname }` );
    },
} );

const upload = multer( { storage } );

router.post( "/upload", upload.single( "file" ), ( req, res ) => {
    res.send();
} );
```

I searched a little bit but not luck. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164372/prevent-redirect-on-file-upload-through-form-submittal-react-express-multer). Before seeing this I had already tried event.preventDefault(). Also, I've tried many things like uploading directly with onChange() without setting a state then handling it with onSubmit(). Before simplifying the code (like posting directly in handleFormSubmit) I was trying to do this via Redux actions but for debugging purposes I moved it here.

Answer (score 1):

It is the first example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

```
handleFormSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault() // <-- missing this
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append( "file", this.state.file );
    const response = await axios.post( "/api/upload", formData );
}

handleFileChange = ( e ) => {
    this.setState( { file: e.target.files[ 0 ] } );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I said I've already tried e.preventDefault() and that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

> This is happening because of hot-reloading comes with Creact React App.

I ran into this issue too, but using plain `webpack` without CRA. I was uploading the files to a static dir served by `webpack-dev-server`. I fixed it by setting `devServer.static.watch` to `false` ([webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#watch)).

Answer (score 0):

your are using

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

this is why refreshing

so do it like this

```
<button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm handling this in the form with onSubmit. I've tried your suggestion but as I guessed did not work.

Comment: try onClick not onclick

Comment: Pretty weird. If I use form for input the app refreshes but if I omit form as you used it does not. But, at the end of the day I want a form there and mange the submit via it. Do you have any idea about what causes this?

Comment: this have not relation to react but to html, if using type submit the page refresh after submitting. you need send data when click button , so do it with onClick

Comment: I'm already doing this with onClick as you suggested. Problem is getting weird because it refreshes now without form. Not always but time to time it does. I don't have any clue what causes this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166832/discussion-between-devserkan-and-dkhili-amine).

Comment: Thank you for your help @Dkhili amine. It turned out this is a bug on CRA side. Seems a total time loss but while struggling I've learned so much :)

Answer (score 0):

remove this from multer

```
    destination( req, file, cb ) {
     cb( null, "client/public/images" );
    },
```