# Image upload not work laravel 5.4 doesn't get any error

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know where do I doing wrong the file not uploaded and the name not store in database.

Here's my controller

```
      if(Input::hasFile('photo')) {
        $fotoName = 'peg' . $employee->id . '.' .
        $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file('photo')->move(
        base_path() . '/public/images/employee/', $fotoName
        );
        $img = Image::make(base_path() . '/public/images/employee/' . $fotoName);
        $img->resize(150, null, function ($constraint) {
          $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $img->save();
        $employee_fotos = Karyawan::find($employee->id);
        $employee_fotos->photo = $fotoName;
        $employee_fotos->save();
      }
```

Views

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{{ route("karyawan.store") }}" method="post" multiple>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar">
          <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>

          <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

and I dont get any error and if I make validate its always get please add image or make sure the file extention .jpg etc, for sure I have choice a right image and extention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `form` tag:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="{{ route("karyawan.store") }}" method="post" multiple>
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="row">
      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar">
          <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>

          <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{

    //dd(request()->all());

    $this->validate(request(), [
        'file'              => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:6000',

    ]);



    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->file->move(public_path('/images/employee/'), $imageName);
```

}

This should work for you but it will store image with a unix timestamp name. If you use the employer id to store images you might have duplicate images in your storage folder next time you upload a new image with the same employee account. 
Also add *enctype="multipart/form-data"* to your form attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Image Upload not working all round, the problem is the browser is just not giving the full file path for the server to upload.

To verify you can do an alert on the value of the input type to see what I mean

```
<input type="file" name="photo" onchange="alert(this.value)" class="form-control" />
```

Go over to [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath/19137745#19137745) for the full solution to the problem

read the answer from 'chakroun yesser'