# how to get the path of the selected document in the file input?

Tags: angular, file, typescript

A block of Html template looks something like this,

```
<div class="field" style="padding:1%">
            <label>Ledger Sample Copies</label>
        <input type="file" formControlName="savingsfile" [(ngModel)]="category.filepath" (change)= "FilePathHandler($event)" >

    </div>
```

and my respective component method looks like this,

```
FilePathHandler(fileName) {

  console.log("Files :",fileName.target.value);
  console.log("Files :",this.category.filepath);
}
```

I am trying to print and insert the path of any document selected from the file input into a database table.

But i am not able to display the filepath in the console.log.

The example output i got for the console logs are below,

Files : C:\fakepath\linux_java_eclipse.txt
Files : undefined

I want to display the actual path of the file not with any fakepath.

could someone please help me out ?

I am working on ubuntu 7.14 machine if that helps out.

Comment: fileName.target.files[0]

Comment: this code displays an file object which does not contain the path of the document. I want the choosen file path.

Comment: tough this code prints the name of the file but i need the path as well..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display the actual path of the file not with any fakepath.

For security reasons the actual path of selected document is not provided to websites. Only filename and a fake path is provided.

If interested in knowing more, please go through this thread.

[How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)