# "C:\\fakepath\\file.txt" issue when selecting file from filepicker

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to make a function that the user can choose a text file from a file picker and then it will read the file and do some stuff while reading...
I'm having a lot of issues and can't make it work. It does not send back to the controller the correct path only "C:\fakepath\file.txt". I tried putting a  real path manually in the function and it said that it can't find the file... I'm really stuck.
This is my html file:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("FilterFile", "Home",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="textFile">
    </div>
    <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Filter</button>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
}
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').submit(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("FilterFile")',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        fileName: $('#textFile').val()
                    }),
                    success: function (result) {
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Failed");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

This is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult FilterFile(string fileName)
        {
            var resultMessage = "";
            try
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))

                {
                    string line;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

                    {

                        if (line.Split(' ').Count() > 1)
                        {
                             var number = line.Split(' ')[0];
                            line.Replace(number, "");

                        }

                    }

                }

                resultMessage = "The task was completed successfully!!";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                resultMessage = ex.Message;
            }
            return Json(resultMessage);

        }
    }
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me since I'm new to programming.Thanks.

Comment: You can't access the real path from browser due to obvious security issues

Comment: You cannot reliably retrieve the full file path from the client. This is a security feature of browsers. There is absolutely no reason for you to need to know the folder structure of the client anyway.

Comment: but  stream reader needs the full path. How do I read the file that the user chose with the filepicker?

Comment: You will need to receive the data of the file on the server side code, the file name isn't enough to save it.

Comment: how do I do that? I'm new to this. can you explain how. thanks.

Comment: For more about C:\fakepath, see [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4851595)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `HttpPostedFileBase` as the parameter recieved by the method. Then get the stream using `HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream()`. Also don't use the ajax because that is just sending the file name when you want to send the file data.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FilterFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var resultMessage = "";
    try
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var stream = file.InputStream();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {

                string line = "";
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    if (line.Split(' ').Count() > 1)
                    {
                        var number = line.Split(' ')[0];
                        line.Replace(number, "");

                    }

                }

            }
        }
        resultMessage = "The task was completed successfully!!";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        resultMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return Json(resultMessage);
}
```