# How to get full path from html input file ? like this C:/User/Desktop/something.png

Tags: javascript, html

How to get full path from html input file ? Like this C:/user/desktop/something.png But is's coming something.png or C:/fakepatch/something.png

Comment: share some of your code will help us understand

Comment: It depends on the server and operating system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: do you mean a file that is selected using `<input type="file">`? then, it's none of your concern

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. This is a security measure implemented by the browser.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#example-4aa6dac8

> For historical reasons, the value IDL attribute prefixes the file name with the string "C:\fakepath\". Some legacy user agents actually included the full path (which was a security vulnerability).

If you were able to see the full path, you might be able to compromise the user's privacy. For example, it might leak their user name, full name, type of computer they're on, etc.