# Cordova get path to file from <input type="browse"/> JavaSctipt

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to find how to get path to file when user clicks on browse button and selects file from IOS/Android  device because what get is C://fakepath/filename

Comment: You will never be able to retrieve an absolute filesystem path from an HTML file input element as that would pose a major security hazard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)