# HTML: How to use Browse [input type="file"] and retrieve selected directory in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, input, electron

Getting "C:/fakepath" for selected directory. So can anyone please help me to get the selected directory.

```
var dialogElement = document.createElement('dialog');
dialogElement.style.width = '80vw';
dialogElement.style.height = '30vh';
dialogElement.setAttribute("id", "test");

document.getElementById('ExportIntermediateForm').appendChild(dialogElement);

$('dialog').html(
    `<label>Select Directory</label>
     <input type="file" id="directorySelector" onchange="FilePath()" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
     <p id="path"></p>`
);


dialogElement.showModal();

function FilePath() {
     console.log("Here I need selected directory");
}
```

Comment: Please search for your issue before posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath

Comment: Yes. But It's not resolved. I need the local directory on in javascript after completing browse.

Comment: Did you read the link? "Some browsers have a security feature that prevents JavaScript from knowing your file's local full path."

Comment: Yes. But How can I achieve that by any other way? Please help me.

Comment: Read the thread! You either use `document.getElementById("file-id").files[0].path` if that doesn't work then your browser doesn't support it and it can't be done

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use electron window for this. You can directly get path using input type file if you use electron windows dialog.