# What is wrong with this code for uploading and immediately displaying an image in Angular?

Tags: angular, image, file-upload

This is in profile.component.html

```
<label for="profile">Profile Photo</label>
<input type="file" [(ngModel)]='input'/>
<img [src]='input'>
```

This is in profile.component.ts

```
profilePhoto: File;

set input(temp: File) {
    this.profilePhoto = temp;
 }

get input() {
    return this.profilePhoto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the `[(ngModel)]` on the File Input is actually providing a string, not a File object in here; `set input(temp: File) { .. }`.

Since some browsers protect the file path, this string path is often virtual (i.e. C:\fakepath\image.png). There are some work arounds but these are inconsistent across browsers. See more about this here; [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

> Some browsers have a security feature that prevents JavaScript from
>   knowing your file's local full path. It makes sense - as a client, you
>   don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem. It
>   would be nice if all browsers did this.

In your case, you can simply use a FileReader to load the image data for your Image element. This is a similar process to what you might use if you want to later upload the file data too.

```
const fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.readAsDataURL(this.profilePhoto);
fReader.onloadend = (event) => {
  this.profilePhotoImage = event.target.result;
}
```

Working example here;
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfvlhn