# I am unable to get full file path in angular from component.html file

Tags: angular, typescript, filepath

I am unable to get full file path in component.ts file,

code from component.html,

```
     <input type="file"  (change)="handleFileInput($event)" class="form-control" formControlName="cv" >
```

code from component.ts

```
 handleFileInput(event :any) {
    
    /*
    let files : FileList  = event.target.files;
    this.imageShow = files[0]; */ //this approach did not worked too

    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (event: any) => {
          this.imageShow = event.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
```

[image: this.imageShow is giving some large string in base64 format like this ,]

can someone help to get actual full path so that I can make apicall with that path..

[image: here is the version details,]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: You don’t need the full path to upload the file. And you won’t be able to get it anyway for security reasons..

Comment: I need the full path to make a different (post)api call.which takes full path of the file as form in the body.how would I do it?

Comment: @MikeOne you are right thanks.