Browse for a folder and get the folder location in input text field using HTML and JavaScript
I have a use case where

User clicks on select folder button(or folder icon)
browse for a folder from file explorer/windows explorer
User selects the folder
click "ok" on the file explorer
display the path of the folder in an input text field

Any help would be appreciated
I have tried below
  <input type="file" webkitdirectory>

but this only has option to upload and I am not able to get the directory path

(Please note that JavaScript is not Java + Script)

Access to the client file system is generally very restricted. What do you intend to do with the full folder path?

I have to add this in JENKINS as a part of parameterized project, This is part of an internal project, If not possible with JavaScript which other scripting can be used?

I only need the folder location.

Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/why-do-browsers-present-selected-files-as-coming-from-c-fakepath-instead-of-th
